# Automatic call recording on MS Teams using GraphApi

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a bot that would automatically join and record calls and meetings on teams for auditing purposes for my company.I did come across a GitHub repo on teams from Microsoft however there are no clear instructions on how to implement it.

Also I get a lot of errors while trying to build the project

Please let me know if anyone of you has done it at your end by any chance or if you have any detailed documentation on how to implement it.

Below is the link to the GitHub Repo.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/a3943bafd73ce0df780c0e1ac3428e3...

## Error Details

While building the project , I get the below errors

*****Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Calls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph.Communications' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    CRFrontEnd  F:\MITL Training\microsoft-graph-comms-samples-master\Samples\V1.0Samples\LocalMediaSamples\PolicyRecordingBot\FrontEnd\Bot\Bot.cs  14  Active*****

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnhbB.png)

I have installed both.net framework 4.6 and 4.8 Developer and runtime , no luck

I also tried to change the target framework , However could not find .vscproj file.

Also modified Visual Studi 2019 installation and unchecked the target framework and selected it back again after completing the installation , but the error persists

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me with this.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what errors you get?

Comment: @Markus-Hermann Thank you for the response , updated the question with details , Hope it helps , Also needed help in setting up the environment for bot deployment as mentioned in the github link provided